# When do I need the Logger object?

Tags: python, logging

I recently found some tutorials for the `logging` module in python, and I am not sure whether it is enough to use e.g. `logging.info()` or if I will need the `Logger` object.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info("test logging")

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("test logger")
```

Both messages will go to `test.log`, but instead of `root`, the second one will say `__main__`.

e.g. [the how-to](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/logging.html) first explains logging without the `Logger` object in the basic tutorial. The [advanced tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial) then introduces the `Logger` object and says:

> Loggers expose the interface that application code directly uses.

Maybe someone could give me a tiny example of what that means, or what the advantage of the objects really are?

Comment: Have you read [the section on loggers](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/logging.html#loggers)? The example you post above is pretty useful already: if you have multiple modules, wouldn't you rather know where a message came from than always see `root`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the tip! I just tested it with a second module. I did not know what to make of this `__main__`, before.